# How to format the audio tag in Ruby Slim?

Tags: ruby, audio, slim-lang

This is the HTML audio tag:

```
<audio controls autoplay loop muted>
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

How is this written in Slim code, including the control, auto play and loop attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the empty attributes with [boolean attributes](http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/file/README.md#Boolean_attributes) in Slim. I guess your HTML snippet translates to something like this:

```
audio controls=true autoplay=true loop=true muted=true
  source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg"
  source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"

  | Your browser does not support the audio tag.
```

or shorter

```
audio(controls autoplay loop muted)
  …
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails, you can also use the audio_tag helper: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/audio_tag